# PhpStorm 2021.1 cannot connect to deployment server using SFTP, but other clients can

Tags: phpstorm, sftp

On my PC I have:

- WinSCP
- FileZilla
- PhpStorm

I configured long time ago a deployment to my server using SFTP. Today PhpStorm told me 'connection refused'.

Using same username and password and ports, WinSCP and FileZilla successfully connected to my server.

So I deleted deployment host and SSH configuration inside PhpStorm

Entering SSH connection, triple checked username, password, port, IP, I still got connection refused, but other SFTP clients on my PC can connect without any issue.

What can I do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: *"What can I do to diagnose the problem?"* Enable extra logging and see the logs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs. If you are unable to make anything out of that -- contact JetBrains Support via entry in the "PhpStorm | Help" menu (where you can provide logs privately). It could be your `known_hosts` / ssh config file that IDE does not like .. or some issue with the library that they use for SSH connectivity (I have seen a few tickets that could be related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved thanks to add logs as suggested by @LazyOne comment

I find a `./ssh/config` file with host name overrides inside of it.

I removed the override, and now PhpStorm can successfully connects